# Como trabalhar com PDF no CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, pdf

```php
function cadastra_pesquisa() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('d_c_p_p', 'Domínio do conteúdo por parte do palestrante', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('i_c_b', 'Instalações e coffee break', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('h_p_c_g', 'Habilidade do palestrante na condução do grupo', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('a_g_p', 'Avaliação Geral da Palestra', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('c_a', 'Conteúdo Apresentado', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data['info_sis'] = $this->db->get('info_sismarket')->result();
        $this->load->view('header_html');
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('pesquisa/pesquisa_satisfacao_erro_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_html');
    } else {
        $pesquisa['d_c_p_p'] = $this->input->post('d_c_p_p');
        $pesquisa['i_c_b'] = $this->input->post('i_c_b');
        $pesquisa['h_p_c_g'] = $this->input->post('h_p_c_g');
        $pesquisa['a_g_p'] = $this->input->post('a_g_p');
        $pesquisa['c_a'] = $this->input->post('c_a');
        $pesquisa['s_c'] = $this->input->post('s_c');

        $this->load->model('usuario_model');
        $this->usuario_model->GravaPesquisa($pesquisa);

        $this->load->view('header_html');
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('pesquisa/pesquisa_satisfacao_ok_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_html');
    }
}
```

Comment: tem algum problema específico que você está encontrando? Na forma atual, a pergunta está difícil de ser respondida.

Comment: Olá bigown! Preciso gerar um relatório com informações vinda do banco.

Comment: Você precisa dar mais detalhes, o que você já fez, onde o problema está. Não tem como as pessoas darem um resposta real saber melhor o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Por favor edite a questão colocando mais informações, onde vocês está na resolução do problema e onde precisa chegar.

Comment: Ok! @bigown, vou tentar explicar melhor minha dúvida, para que vocês posam me ajudar! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara você precisa basicamente fazer uma consulta no banco, montar um HTML com resultado da consulta e depois utilizar o DOMPDF para renderizar o HTML.

Tente utilizar tabelas e evitar uso de CSS pois o DOMPDF possui algumas limitações.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Da forma como perguntou e o conteúdo em si postado não ajuda muito, tem algum problema específico?

Ve se ajuda
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf

Comment: Links isoladamente podem se perder no tempo e precisamos de respostas duradouras aqui. Seria melhor esperar ele dar mais detalhes para dar uma informação relevante que possa ser achada aqui por outros desenvolvedores.

Answer (score 0):

Se voce for usar a saia do PDF apenas com tabelas(igual eu tive que usar) sugiro dar uma olhada no DataTables com o plugin TableTools